# VBA how to calculate depth of items in excel, simliar to a BOM system

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a macro that takes a excel spreadsheet which has a parent column and a child column. The idea of the macro is it calculates each products depth in a BOM tree. The spreadsheet can also have several BOM trees in it.

I've thought of having the root of the tree be given an initial value of 0 and then doing a check of it's children and take their parents value and adding 1. But I don't know how to do it efficently since the way I am thinking I need to have some realtion based check and iterate it thorugh the entire BOM tree but I can't figure out a good solution for it.

What I have done so far is to get which product is a parent to another product, but I am stuck at the part of how to calculate the depth.

This is what I currently have done.

```
Sub findParents(startRange As String, searchValue As String, endRow As String, realtionArray() As String)
    Do While True
        With Worksheets("Test").range(startRange & endRow)
        Set c = .Find(searchValue, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If c Is Nothing Then ' string not found
                Exit Do
            Else ' string found
                startRange = "B" & CStr(c.Row + 1)
                Debug.Print c & "'s parent is " & range("A" & CStr(c.Row)).value
            End If
        End With
    Loop
End Sub
Sub BOM()

    Dim c As range
    Dim searchValue As String
    Dim startRange As String
    Dim endRow As String
    Dim searchValues() As Variant
    Dim iNum As Integer
    Dim varData As Variant
    Dim relationArray() As String
    
    
    endRow = ":B" & CStr(range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    searchValues = range("D2:D" & CStr(range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))

    For iNum = 1 To UBound(searchValues)
        startRange = "B2"
        searchValue = searchValues(iNum, 1)
        findParents startRange, searchValue, endRow, relationArray
    Next iNum
    
    
 End Sub
```

This is the test data I'm working with.

[image]

Comment: So you can have the same child (`H`) with several parents? What if the parent has also 2 parents - which way do you want to go up?

Comment: Yeah there can be several BOM trees with same values in it. I don't know which way is the most efficent I've heared that there used sto be a macro that used recursion and went bottom up but I can't figure out how it was structured.

Comment: If there are "several BOM trees" then there's no way to distinguish between [3 trees, each with root A] and [one tree with root A which has 3 children].

Comment: ...unless the trees share no common elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```vb
Sub DoLevels()
    
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim lvl As Long, children As New Collection, child
    
    Set rng = Range("A2:C11")
    
    rng.Columns(3).ClearContents
    lvl = 2
    'collect all the "root" parents
    For Each c In rng.Columns(1).Cells
        If IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, rng.Columns(2), 0)) Then
            c.Offset(0, 2).Value = lvl
            children.Add Array(c.Offset(0, 1).Value, lvl) 'store immediate children and level
        End If
    Next c
    
    'walk down the tree for each child
    Do While children.Count > 0
        child = children(1)(0) 'next child item in queue
        lvl = children(1)(1)   'child item level
        children.Remove 1      'remove from collection
        For Each c In rng.Columns(1).Cells
            If c.Value = child And Len(c.Offset(0, 2).Value) = 0 Then
                c.Offset(0, 2).Value = lvl + 1
                children.Add Array(c.Offset(0, 1).Value, lvl + 1) 'add child to queue
            End If
        Next c
    Loop

End Sub
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create in the sheet a ActiveX Microsoft Treeview Control (version 6.0) named "TreeView1" with "/" as PathSeparator (to be sure specify the separator even if it's already it) and run this macro:

```
Sub SubTree()
    
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim str As String
    Dim mynode As Node
    Dim Index As Double
    Dim MaxIndex As Double
    Dim MinIndex As Double
    Dim lvl As Double
    
    Set rng = Range("A2:E11")
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set obj = ActiveSheet.Shapes("TreeView1")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If obj Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Create in the sheet a ActiveX Microsoft Treeview Control (version 6.0) named ""TreeView1"" with ""/"" as PathSeparator and re-run the macro", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    obj.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Nodes.Clear
    
    For Each cell In rng.Columns(1).Cells
        If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng.Columns(2), cell.Value2) = 0 Then
            On Error Resume Next
            obj.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Nodes.Add Key:=cell.Value2, Text:=cell.Value2
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next
    
    MinIndex = 1
    
    
CP_Child_Nodes_Start:
    MaxIndex = obj.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Nodes.Count
    For Index = MinIndex To MaxIndex
        Set mynode = obj.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Nodes(Index)
        For Each cell In rng.Columns(1).Cells
            If cell.Value2 = Split(mynode.Key, "\")(UBound(Split(mynode.Key, "\"))) Then
                Debug.Print mynode.FullPath
                If Len(Replace(mynode.FullPath, "\" & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value2, "")) = Len(mynode.FullPath) Then
                    obj.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Nodes.Add mynode, tvwChild, mynode.FullPath & "\" & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value2, cell.Offset(0, 1).Value2
                Else
                    If Left(mynode.Text, 6) <> "#LOOP:" Then
                        obj.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Nodes.Add mynode, tvwChild, mynode.FullPath & "\" & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value2, "#LOOP:" & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value2
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
    
    If MinIndex > MaxIndex Then GoTo CP_Child_Nodes_End
    MinIndex = MaxIndex + 1
    
    GoTo CP_Child_Nodes_Start
    
CP_Child_Nodes_End:
    
    For Each cell In rng.Columns(1).Cells
        str = cell.Value2 & "\" & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value2
        lvl = 0
        For Each mynode In obj.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Nodes
            
            If Not mynode.Parent Is Nothing Then
                
                If Len(Replace(mynode.Key, str, "")) <> Len(mynode.Key) Then
                    
                    For Index = Len(mynode.Key) To 1 Step -1
                        
                        If Left(Right(mynode.Key, Index), Len(str)) = str Then
                            Exit For
                        End If
                        
                    Next
                    
                    lvl = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Max(lvl, UBound(Split(Left(mynode.Key, Len(mynode.Key) - Index), "\")))
                    Debug.Print
                    Debug.Print mynode.Key
                    Debug.Print mynode.Text
                    Debug.Print mynode.FullPath
                    If mynode.Parent Is Nothing Then
                        Debug.Print "."
                    Else
                        Debug.Print mynode.Root
                    End If
                    Debug.Print str, lvl
                End If
            End If
        Next
        
        cell.Offset(0, 4).Value2 = lvl
        lvl = 0
    Next
End Sub
```